# How to ALWAYS include new files in a folder in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have a project in visual studio 2017 for making a WinJS UWP windows 10 app. I'm using babel to compile some files from one folder and put them in another -- > `jsx/src` includes my .jsx files, and they get compiled into `jsx/out`.

I've set up a babel watcher to watch the jsx/src file and output a new file to jsx/out, *but for now every new file I add, I have to manually add it in visual studio* so that it shows in the folder. I'd like this to be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for this now! Didn't realize this was left unanswered.

The answer is to modify the `project.jsproj` file directly. Open your project folder, find the file called `{projectname}.jsproj` and open it in your favorite text editor.

For my use case, I wanted to:

1. Fully include the 'bundle.js' file in /jsx/out
2. Include, but not export with the build, any .js / .jsx files in /jsx/src

So I added these lines:

```
<None Include="jsx\src\**\*.jsx" />
<None Include="jsx\src\**\*.js" />
<Content Include="jsx\out\bundle.js" />
```

"None" means the files are shown in Visual Studio, still remain debuggable, but don't end up getting put in with the files when you build it for the windows store.

Now any new files get included in when they're added to the appropriate folder (sometimes you might have to force reload the project to see them)

Comment: Correct. Use the star pattern, and remove individual files. Win win for everyone.